Heterodyne measurement gives us complex measurement result?
Quantum mechanics tell us that the measurement result can possess real values. However, in quantum optics, there's a kind of measurement called heterodyne measurement which can be described mathematically using POVM
$$
\Pi _{\alpha}\equiv \left\{ \frac{1}{\pi}|\alpha \rangle \langle \alpha | \right\} _{\alpha \in \mathbb{C}}\tag1
$$
where $|\alpha \rangle$ is the coherent state and $\alpha$ is a complex number in general. Now, suppose we have one quantum state $\rho$, then, by definition of POVM, the probability of obtaining one measurement result $\alpha$ is $\mathrm{tr}\left[ \rho |\alpha \rangle \langle \alpha | \right] /\pi$.
My question is, $\alpha$ is a complex number in general. How can we obtain a complex number during one experiment?

A heterodyne measurement does not measure $\alpha$. It rather projects onto the coherent state basis and returns a number.
The coherent state is an eigenstate of the annihilation operator $\hat a |\alpha\rangle = \alpha|\alpha\rangle$. So to measure $\alpha$, we would have to observe $\langle\alpha|\hat a|\alpha\rangle$. But, as you point out, $\hat a$ is not an observable, in particular, it is not Hermitian. We can easily construct a Hermitian operator from it which is an observable, $\hat a^\dagger \hat a$, i.e. the number operator. This operator has the expectation value $\langle\alpha|\hat a^\dagger \hat a|\alpha\rangle = |\alpha|^2$, which is a real number.
The important point here is that just because something is an eigenvalue, it doesn't mean it is an observable.

In one POVM, $\alpha$ is only one label, labeling which measurement result we have. The label is immaterial. For instance, if we have two sets of POVM $\left\{ |x\rangle \langle x| \right\} _x$ and $\left\{ |y\rangle \langle y| \right\} _y$, we can combine them into one POVM in a larger Hilbert space as $\left\{ |x\rangle \langle x|\otimes |y\rangle \langle y| \right\} _{x,y}$, or if we like, we can relabel this POVM as $\left\{ |\alpha \rangle \langle \alpha | \right\} _{\alpha}$ with $\alpha =x+iy$. The statement that the measurement result can only be real means the eigenvalue of the observable is real.
